# Why does the infinite union exist in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I want to be clear that I am not asking about the axiom of union. I understand that for an infinite set $A$, $\bigcup A$ exists. My question is specifically about the more widely used (as far as I have seen) version of the notation:
$\bigcup_{b\in B} S_b$.

The technical issue that seems to appear to me is that applying the axiom of union requires first the construction of a set $A$ such that $x\in A \iff \exists b\in B(x= S_b)$.

Clearly in the case that the indexing set $B$ is finite, iterated application of the axiom of pairing with axiom of union can give the required set, but when $B$ is infinite I cannot see any way to justify $A$'s existence, and thus existence of the union in general.

Comment: You don't have that issue at all. In order to talk about "indexing", you need a collection $\{S_b\}_{b\in B}$ to begin with. Even if by "indexing" you understand some bijection $f:B\to\{S_b\}$ you still need the right side to exist a priori.

Comment: Note that $b\mapsto S_b$ is a function on $B$. Hence the class $\{S_b\colon b\in B\}$ is a set by the axiom schema of replacement.

Comment: How do you define the $S_b$ from the start? I have seen $\bigcup_{b \in B} b$ for the axiom of Union already, but not something with this other $S$ symbol.

Comment: @freakish $b \to S_b$ could be a class function defined by some predicate and then replacement is needed in general (but that's no problem).

Comment: Such indexed families are a convenient shorthand but one should be aware they're just "special sets" (or "class predicates" depending on context).

Comment: @freakish As long as that formula is a class function, its restriction on $B$ is a function by the replacement schema. I agree that the replacement schema is not necessary here. But in many occasions when discussing an indexed family of sets $(X_i)_{i\in I}$, we do not really care enough to build a set that contains all $X_i$. I personally find it a good practice to just use the (overpowered) replacement schema to simplify the thought process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An indexed family $S_b, b \in B$ is a set $I$ already: namely consisting of ordered pairs (pairing axiom) $(b,x)$ where $b \in B$, and which is "functional":

$$\forall z \in I: \exists x,y: (z=(x,y) \land x \in B) \text{ and } \forall b \in B: \exists x: (b,x) \in I \text{ and } \forall b \in B: \forall x,x': ((b,x) \in I \land (b,x') \in I) \to x=x'$$

So the second part of the pair $(b,x) \in I$ is the set we denote $S_b$, but the total collection (assignment) $I$ must already be a set in the universe.

And it's straightforward to define the union $\bigcup_{b \in B} S_b$ from $I$: define the range of $I$ first, and apply the union axiom to that.

If however $S_b$ is defined by some predicate, we can apply the replacement axiom instance for that predicate to get the range as a set in our universe as well.